Is $L^1([0,1])$ weakly $\sigma$-compact?
It is known that the Banach space $X:=L^1([0,1])$ is weakly compactly generated.
I want to cover not only a dense subspace but the whole part of the Banach space $X$ with weakly compact subsets if possible.
Can we construct an increasing sequence of weakly compact subsets of $X$ whose union is $X$?

No, $X$ is not weakly $\sigma$-compact. Indeed, any weakly compact $K \subset L^1([0,1])$ must have no interior under the norm topology. Assume to the contrary that $K$ has norm-interior. By translating and scaling, we may assume $B(0, 1) \subset K$, where $B(0, 1)$ is the closed unit ball around the origin. But then the sequence,
$$f_n = n1_{[0, \frac{1}{n}]}$$
is contained in $K$. Yet, it can have no weakly convergent subnet. Indeed, if it admits a subnet $f_{n_\lambda}$ which weakly converges to some $f \in L^1([0,1])$, then, for any $0 < \epsilon < 1$, we have,
$$\int f1_{[\epsilon,1]} \, dx = \lim_\lambda \int f_{n_\lambda}1_{[\epsilon,1]} \, dx = 0$$
as $\lim_n \int f_n1_{[\epsilon,1]} \, dx = 0$. By dominated convergence, this implies $\int f \, dx = 0$. However, as $\int f_n \, dx = 1$ for all $n$, we must have $\int f \, dx = 1$, which is a contradiction. This means $f_n$ has no weakly convergent subnet, contradicting the weak compactness of $K$. Hence, $K$ has no norm-interior.
But this implies, were $X$ weakly $\sigma$-compact, it must be the union of countably many weakly compact subsets, each of which is clearly norm-closed, and, per above, also without interior in the norm topology. Thus, $X$ is the union of countably many sets which are nowhere dense in the norm topology, which is impossible per Baire category theorem.

Also, perhaps you meant “weakly compactly generated” in a different way, but if you meant it as $X$ is a $k$-space under the weak topology (i.e., $U \subset X$ is weakly open iff $U \cap K$ is weakly open in $K$ for all $K \subset X$ weakly compact), then $X$ being weakly compactly generated is not true. See, for example, the beginning of section $5$ of this paper.

Thank you. You are my angel.
